# JPA IN clause for one to many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following jpa entities:

```
Music_playlist[

    Integer music_id;

    Integer playlist_id;

    List<Genre> genres;
]

Genre[
    Integer genre_id;
]
```

I want to know if I can make a named query that is going to retrieve **music_playlist** entities which their genres attributes contains a genre object with a **genre_id** equals to a named param. Something like this:

```
SELECT mp FROM music_playlist WHERE :genreId in mp.genres.genre_id
```

Comment: Inspection of any JPQL reference would tell you that "{xxx} IN {yyy}" is for a {yyy} that is a Collection, and "genre_id" is an Integer. Present WHAT you have tried and what exception or generated SQL you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ANY

```
 FROM MusicPlaylist mp WHERE 'Rock' = ANY (SELECT g.genreId FROM mp.genres g)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be:

```
SELECT mp FROM music_playlist mp JOIN mp.genres g WHERE :genreId = g.genreId
```